# Own Posts Not Showing Up in StackOverFlow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, posts, owner

on stackoverflow.com under questions.. whenever i post a question i never seem to see it under "questions".

other can see it as the view count goes up.

i was just wondering if not displaying own posts is the default behaviour or is there something wrong with IExplorer?

thanks.

EDIT: it is happening here also (meta)

Comment: What tab do you have selected? I use "Active" here on Meta and your question shows up fine.

Comment: Ya this is common. Perhaps your browser's cache needs to be cleared? Anyway, it's not a problem.

Comment: `is there something wrong with IExplorer?` Oh boy, where should I start

Comment: @Kop: well, you could start by recording a CD of all the angry rants made by web designers forced to make a site IE-Compatible. (Did I just use IE and compatible in the same sentence?)

Comment: @George, I don't think a CD will have enough space.

Comment: @Kop: I don't think a massive server farm would be enough... :(

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the `Active` tab selected, try selecting the `Newest` tab up on top.

Otherwise, clear your browser cache and reload the page. Sometimes you can easily force a new uncached copy by holding `Shift` while hitting refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest). Can you see your question there? I can.